Azure VM上のSoftether VPN Clientから自宅PC上のVPN Serverに接続できない
Azure上のVM→自宅PCの接続をSoftether VPNで検証しており、以下の2点でつまづいております。
VPN Client: Azure VM（Ubuntu）
VPN Server: 自宅 laptop PC（Windows）

VPN Clientの仮想NICにdhclientを実行してもプライベートIPが割当たらない。
VPN ClientからVPN Serverへ接続できない。
（確認のため、自宅PCにVPN ClientをインストールしてVPN Serverに接続したのですが失敗しました。）

以下に実装に使用したファイルをまとめてあります。
Dockerfile: VPN Server構築用
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV VERSION v4.43-9799-beta-2023.08.31
ENV HUBNAME HUB
ENV HUBPASS password
ENV USERNAME user001
ENV USERPASS password

WORKDIR /usr/local/vpnserver

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get -y install wget gcc make dos2unix

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/vpnserver/entrypoint.sh
RUN dos2unix /usr/local/vpnserver/entrypoint.sh && \
  chmod 755 /usr/local/vpnserver/entrypoint.sh

RUN wget https://jp.softether-download.com/files/softether/${VERSION}-tree/Linux/SoftEther_VPN_Server/64bit_-_Intel_x64_or_AMD64/softether-vpnserver-${VERSION}-linux-x64-64bit.tar.gz -O /tmp/softether-vpnserver.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvf /tmp/softether-vpnserver.tar.gz -C /usr/local/ && \
  rm /tmp/softether-vpnserver.tar.gz && \
  make && \
  apt-get purge -y -q --auto-remove gcc make wget dos2unix

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/vpnserver/entrypoint.sh"]

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver start

sleep 3s

/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /CMD DynamicDnsSetHostname $HOSTNAME
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /CMD HubCreate $HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /HUB:$HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS /CMD UserCreate $USERNAME /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /HUB:$HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS /CMD UserPasswordSet $USERNAME /PASSWORD:$USERPASS
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /HUB:$HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS /CMD SecureNatEnable
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /HUB:$HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS /CMD DhcpGet
/usr/local/vpnserver/vpncmd /SERVER localhost /HUB:$HUBNAME /PASSWORD:$HUBPASS /CMD DhcpEnable

tail -f /dev/null

setup-vpn-server.sh: VPN Server設定用
#!/bin/bash


docker build -t vpn-server:latest .

docker run -d --name vpn-server --hostname vpnserver --cap-add NET_ADMIN -p 500:500/udp -p 4500:4500/udp -p 1701:1701/tcp -p 1194:1194/udp -p 5555:5555/tcp vpn-server:latest

connect-vpn.sh: VPN Client用
#!/bin/bash

# NIC NAME
NIC="nic01"
# Account name
ACCOUNT="account01"
# Server name
SERVER="vpnserver.softether.net:5555"
# Hub name
HUB="HUB"
# User name
USERNAME="user001"
# Password
PASSWORD="password"
# type (standard or radius)
TYPE="standard"

SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd "$SCRIPT_DIR"/vpnclient

sudo cat <<EOF > $SCRIPT_DIR/setup.txt
NicCreate $NIC
NicList
AccountCreate $ACCOUNT /SERVER:$SERVER /HUB:$HUB /USERNAME:$USERNAME /NICNAME:$NIC
AccountPasswordSet $ACCOUNT /PASSWORD:$PASSWORD /TYPE:$TYPE
AccountConnect $ACCOUNT
AccountList
EOF

sudo $SCRIPT_DIR/vpncmd /client localhost /in:$SCRIPT_DIR/setup.txt
rm $SCRIPT_DIR/setup.txt

sudo dhclient vpn_$NIC


接続できないときに、クライアント側でログファイル等をまず確認すべきかと思います。

ログは確認したのですが、接続失敗したのでサーバーホスト名、ポートが正しいか確認する旨が記載されているのみでした。

以下の2点を改修することで、VPNクライアントからVPNサーバーへの接続は確認できました。
・サーバーでVPN Azureを有効にする
・Dockerコンテナーのネットワークドライバをhostにする
ただ、新たな問題が1点発生しております。
【新たな問題】
クライアント側のルーティング情報がサーバーマネージャー上で確認できない
これは、dhclientでIPが割当たらないことが原因では？と疑っております。

無事に解消したので、問題と対策をまとめておきます。
【問題】
1.dhclientでクライアントの仮想NICにIPアドレスが割当たらない
2.クライアント側のルーティング情報がVPNサーバーマネージャーで確認できない
【対策】
1.Softether VPNのフルトンネルを止め、目当てのネットワークへのルーティング情報を静的に追加
2.1が解消することで解決
dhclientで割り当たっていないと思っていたのは勘違いで、割当たっていました。
（接続が確立するまでにdhclientを打っていたので時間がかかった。）
ただ、dhclient成功直後、クライアントVMへのSSH接続が切断されました。
Softetherは仕様上、フルトンネルで全てのパケットがVPNトンネルに向かうためだと思われます。
今回は必要なネットワークアドレス帯が決まっていたので、クライアント側でスタティックルートを設定し、サーバー側ではデフォルトルートの広報を止めることで、今回の事象は解決しました。

解決した場合にはコメント欄ではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。
